# Add small arrow image after each 1st level nav item

Tags: magento, hyperlink, navigation

im working with magentos main navigation and i would like to simply add an arrow image aftger each of the 1st level menu items. This should be a simple thing but i cant work out how to do it.

I have copied nafigation.phtml into my local mage file and chnage it from this:

```
 $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
```

To this, to test it:

```
 $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '<span>Hello World</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
```

But no changes get made and i don't see hello world after the menu items.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply done with CSS but you need to show me the HTML output aside the PHP code.

If your menu items are generated something like this:

```
<ul class="menu-items">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use one of these:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp

Comment: Thanks i didnt think of adding a background image but works a treat!

Comment: Yes that would be the best option. Cheers.